# Compile Error Expected Function Or Variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new and trying to learn VBA. When I'm typing in the code I get Compile Error Expected Function Or Variable.

Is something regarding the activecell, but can't figure it out.

```
Sub Testare()
    Dim FilmName As String
    Dim FilmLenght As Integer
    Dim FilmDescription As String

    Range("b10").Select
    FilmName = ActiveCell.Value
    FilmLenght = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

    If FilmLenght < 100 Then
       FilmDescription = "Interesant"
    Else
       FilmDescription = "Suficient"
    End If

    MsgBox FilmName & " is " & FilmDescription
End Sub
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into my VBA and it worked.... It might be somewhere else aside form this code

Comment: Your code compiles and ran fine for me.

Comment: Are you using a non-English version?  Also, unless there was a copy-paste error, "FilmName" should be made consistent throughout the module.

Answer (score 5):

This error happens also when a Sub is called the same as variable (i.e. in one Sub you have for loop with iterator "a", whilst another Sub is called "a").

This gives an error that fits to your description.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to make your code fail in two different ways:

1. Place a very large value in **D10**
2. Place a text value in **D10**

This will result in either an overflow error or type mismatch error.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I ended up with the same error when I created a Sub within a worksheet with the Sub Name the same as the Worksheet name.

Unfortunately when this happens, no error is highlighted by a compile; the error only appears at run time.  Also, the offending line is not highlighted, which makes it a bit difficult to find.

**Changing the Sub name solves it though.**

Answer (score -1):

Here is what caused this error in my case:

Inside a new Public Function that I was starting to write, I began to type a statement, but needed to copy a long varname from another location, so I just inserted the letter `a` to prevent Excel from popping-up the uber-annoying `Compile Error: Expected Expression` dialog. So I had this:

```
myVarName = a
```

I then attempted to step-through my code to get to that point, and when Excel entered that function I received the message `"Compile Error: Expected Function Or Variable"`. To resolve, I just changed the placeholder to a number:

```
myVarName = 1
```

And all continued just fine.

Comment: I don't understand this answer and I can't reproduce the symptom.

Comment: The error message is nebulous (see [Peter Rush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26527334/1447509)) and there is little hint in the error message that an invalid variable declaration caused the error, to wit: `a` !== `"a"` -- that is, `myVarName = "a"` would have worked. Had this answer existed when I searched, it would have jogged my mind and I would have caught my typo earlier than I did, hence this answer for the next bleary-eyed jockey. *I am surprised you could not reproduce or understand the obvious error.* Evidently I did not explain in the answer very well so I will revise it.