# VBA Error 13 : Why is there a mismatch error in Ubound()?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to filter some columns(string and numbers). I defined `var` as `variant`, `sArray`() as `String`. I get an Error type 13 for `sArray (4,5)` here:

```
 ReDim sArray4(1 To UBound(var4))
 'and here
 ReDim sArray5(1 To UBound(var5))
```

`var4` is a string/variant for exp "Consulting & Support" but `UBound(var4)` delivers a mismatch. I don't understand that. `var1`, `var2` and `var3` are also 2D variants like `var4` and `ReDim sArray2(1 To UBound(var2))` ... works fine.

I already saw the questions related to this error. I find nothing helpful

```
Dim Pfad1 As String
Dim Bezeichnung As Variant
Umsatzdatenbank = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Pfad1 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Umsatz").Cells(5, 5)

Dim range1, range2, range3, range4, range5 As Range
lastoffice = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastoffice = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastbez = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastbez2 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastoffice2 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set range1 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("B3:B" & lastbez)
Set range2 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("E3:E" & lastoffice)
Set range3 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("H3:H" & lastoffice)
Set range4 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("C3:C" & lastbez2)
Set range5 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("F3:F" & lastoffice)

Dim var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 As Variant
Dim sArray1(), sArray2(), sArray3(), sArray4(), sArray5()  As String
Dim i As Long

'Bestimmung des Arrays    
var1 = range1.Value
ReDim sArray1(1 To UBound(var1))
For i = 1 To (UBound(var1))
    sArray1(i) = var1(i, 1)
Next

var2 = range2.Value
ReDim sArray2(1 To UBound(var2))
For i = 1 To (UBound(var2))
    sArray2(i) = var2(i, 1)
Next

var3 = range3.Value
ReDim sArray3(1 To UBound(var3))
For i = 1 To (UBound(var3))
    sArray3(i) = var3(i, 1)
Next

var4 = range4.Value
ReDim sArray4(1 To UBound(var4))

For i = 1 To (UBound(var4))
    sArray4(i) = var4(i, 1)
Next

var5 = range5.Value
ReDim sArray5(1 To UBound(var5))

For i = 1 To (UBound(var5))
    sArray5(i) = var5(i, 1)
Next

Workbooks.Open Pfad1
ActiveSheet.Name = ("Quelldatei")
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "FSS"
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   

Range("K1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Worksheets("FSS").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=sArray1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Worksheets("FSS").Range("$A$2:$AA$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Worksheets("FSS").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=sArray2, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Worksheets("FSS").Range("$A$2:$AA$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

'Sheets("FSS").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=sArray3, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Workbooks.Open Pfad1
ActiveSheet.Name = ("Quelldatei")
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Name = "GMS"

Range("K1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Worksheets("Quelldatei").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=sArray4, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Worksheets("Quelldatei").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=sArray5, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Worksheets("Quelldatei").Range("$A$2:$AA$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
Worksheets("GMS").Range("$A$2:$AA$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Paste
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are those one line with the `&` or two lines with the `&` just put here?  If the prior remove it and use two lines.

Comment: You declare your variable incorrectly: `Dim range1, range2, range3, range4, range5 As Range` in this only `range5` gets declared `as Range`, the rest default to `Variant` as you omit the type. You should write: `Dim range1 as Range, range2 as Range...` This holds also for your other declarations.

Comment: It appears your ranges are one cell, so the variables don't contain arrays.

Comment: @Luuklag  yeah you are right but it does not help though.When i don't declare the type of the variable it would be considered automaticly as variant ?

Comment: @Rory yeah the variables don't contain arrays.later i instruct that  array(i)=var(i,1) not inversily. The problem is UBound(var4), because var4 is a 2D variant array, as per tinstruction:
var4 = range4.Value
Because range4 contains mutiple cells, as per instruction:

Set range4 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("C3:C" & lastbez2)                                                                                                              
I guess you mean in UBound(xxx) , xxx should be an arrayname.if var4=range4.Value isn't considered as array How do u suggest to change?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading values from the sheet with varX = rangeX.Value. In case the Range contains more that one cell, the result is a 2-dimensional array. However, if the Range contains only one cell, the result is a single value, not an array - and you cannot use the `UBound`-function for a single (scalar) value.

Now, for the filter, you can pass either a single value or a 1-dimensional array. The code copies the first column of the range data to a new 1-dimensional variable `sArrayX`.

You will have to distinguish for the two cases where you have only one value and for the one where you have several. As you do the whole stuff 5 times, I would suggest to use a function for that:

```
 Function copyToArray(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Variant
    If r.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim a(1 To 1)
        a(1) = r.Value2
    Else
        ReDim a(1 To r.Rows.Count)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
            a(i) = r.Cells(i, 1).Value2
        Next i
    End If
    copyToArray = a

End Function
```

You can call the function like that:

```
Dim sArray1, sArray2, sArray3, sArray4, sArray5 ' Declare as Variant is okay!
sArray1 = copyToArray(range1)
sArray2 = copyToArray(range2)
...
```

The `VarX`-variables are no longer needed. One remark: A variable of type `Variant` can hold *anything*, and that includes arrays. Using Variants to pass arrays from/to a function is often the easiest solution.

And I would strongly suggest that you give your variables more descriptive names.

Comment: Thany you very much for this explanation! I add the function as you described...But i become an Error "Error while compiling
Variable or procedure expected instead of a module" which is bizarre since rangeX is range so r in the function. and a=copyToArray= sArrayX are all variant ?!

Comment: This error is not related to any data types. Probably you are naming a variable like a sub or function or something like that. Maybe check the answers of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274927/compile-error-expected-function-or-variable